# Salesforce: Trying to deliver a CSV from a scheduled job

Tags: salesforce

I read where someone was able to do this, but I'm having a hard time getting it to work.

Basically, I'm scheduling an HTTP callout to a page that has a controller that builds a CSV and emails it to a recipient.

The Scheduled class:

```
global class ReportExporter implements System.Schedulable {
global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
    getmailReportOutput ex = new getmailReportOutput();
    ex.exportCSV();
    }
```

}

The getEmailReportOutput class:

```
public class getmailReportOutput{

    public Static String strSessionID;

    public getmailReportOutput() {
        }

   public void exportCSV() {
        makeReportRequest();
       }

@future (callout=true)      
    public Static void makeReportRequest()  {               
        strHost ='c.cs4.visual.force.com';
        strSessionID = UserInfo.getSessionId();
        String requestUrl =  'https://' + strHost + '/apex/TestSendReport#';        
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(requestUrl);
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setHeader('Cookie','sid=' + strSessionID );
        String output = new Http().send(req).getBody();
        System.debug('HTTP RESPONSE RETURNED: ' + output);
        }
    }
```

The getEmailReportOutput class does an HTTP Callout to a VF page:  I make sure to send the sessionID with the request:
And the "TestSendReport" is just a simple callout to a controller:

```
<apex:page controller="Exporter" action="{!runrpt}">
</apex:page>
```

...And the controller is calling the report content:

```
    public class Exporter {
    public static Boolean isTest;
    public static String strEmailAddr;

    public void runrpt() {
        executeRpt();
        }       
@future          
    public static void executeRpt() {
        System.debug('CALLING REPORT EXPORTER...');        
        String ReportName__c = '00OP0000000Jp3N';
        String strEmailAddr =  'myname@email.com';

        ApexPages.PageReference report = new ApexPages.PageReference( '/' + RptName__c + '?csv=1');

        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        attachment.setFileName('report.csv');
        attachment.setBody(report.getContent());
        attachment.setContentType('text/csv');
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        message.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { attachment } );
        message.setSubject('Report');
        message.setPlainTextBody('The report is attached.');
        message.setToAddresses( new String[] { strEmailAddr } );
        Messaging.sendEmail( new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { message } );        
    }

}
```

...Any ideas?   The debug logs show all is well, but nothing is received. I know this is a wall of code, but it seems to be what people recommend to accomplish the task - I just can't see anything wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything obviously missing here :/

Just to be safe - `getEmailReportOutput` & `getmailReportOutput` are the same class (typo error in the post, not in your actual code)?

This looks like jumping a lot of hops, do I read it correctly that it's scheduled class -> REST callout -> VF page with action -> @future -> send an email? Geez, a lot can go wrong here ;) [I've read somewhere that SF will keep some kind of reference counter](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/7255/799) and calling out to same instance might block you from using page.getContent...

Can you see the report body `System.debug(report.getContent().toString());`? Can you try saving this email as task for your own user or under a sample Account for example (`setSaveAsActivity()`)?

As blatant plug as it is - I've used different path to solve similar requirement. Check out https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4303/scheduled-reports-as-attachment and see if you can get it to work?

Comment: Hi eyescream,thanks - I actually used your post to get to where I am :-) !    I'll try using your suggestion more closely and see if I get further.   BTW- yes, it's a lot of hops... Scheduler --> callout --> report --> Another class ... I was trying to get around the issue of getContent() not working with shechulableContext, but I guess I went overboard.

Comment: Just try making a scheduled class -> REST call to the report page directly and then send email from it ;)

Comment: Hi eyescrem - thanks for your help.   I got it working!    It's actually quite a simplification from your code, but I blogged my answer here:   http://kevindotcar.wix.com/home/apps/blog/how-to-schedule-a-report-to-send

I also plugged your original post too.  Also, two of the steps are out of order, but I think ppl will get the idea.   Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Cool one :) Post this comment as your own answer & accept it. And actually why not posting it (or at least cross linking in the comments) on SF stackexchange too? It's not too different from my complete solution (User wanted to send reports to internal as well as external email addresses, sheduledjob was looping through all config records that had "Monday" written on them etc ;))

Comment: Noo- it's all installed and done... I don't want to see this problem again (for now :-)   -   I'll let your solution stand as the standard :)